# .Net: Is a good idea to use reflection on Android devices, while I'm getting only public fields?

Tags: c#, android, .net, reflection

I'm building an app for android devices with the .net standard (Unity).

And I have used **reflection** to iterate throw all public properties in a model.

I have read some articles about reflection on Java and they didn't recommend using Reflection on JAVA, the reflection will get all the properties even private ones. But on C# is a bit different, we can specify which property to get based on visibility.

So does apply the same and for C#, is it a good idea to use it?

Sorry, I'm new to Reflection, and I couldn't find any information about this case. One benefit of using reflection in my case is that I have to type fewer lines of code.

Here is the code I'm using.

```
    public static KeyValuePair<string, DateTime> IncomingTimingOld(TimingOld timing)
    {
        Type type = typeof(TimingOld);
        Dictionary<string, DateTime> propValues = GetValuesOld(timing, type);
       //...
    }

    private static Dictionary<string, DateTime> GetValuesOld(TimingOld timing, Type type)
    {
        // Get the public properties.
        return type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
            .OrderBy(t => t.GetValue(timing))
            .ToDictionary(t => t.Name, t => Convert.ToDateTime(t.GetValue(timing)));
    }
```

Comment: There's almost always something better to do than use reflection.  That said, there are some usecases where its the only answer.  But without details of why and how you're using it, we can't answer this (and even then its likely to become a pure opinion question which is off topic here).  Also, being on an Android device has no effect on this question, the OS doesn't change the answer.

Comment: Why did you use Reflection in the first place? What problem do you think it was solving?

Comment: @John It is just a bit more readable in my opinion, and I will type fewer lines of code, since all the properties are the same data type, I'm using reflection to iterate throw them.

Comment: @GabeSechan Sorry but some Java engineers said that isn't recommended on Android, but on PC isn't any problem to use it. But again will use it really.
Just updated the question with code samples.

Comment: *"It is just a bit more readable"*. That's a terrible reason to use Reflection. *"I will type fewer lines of code"*. That's a better reason but only if you don't care that the code will be much slower than the alternative. In some cases, the difference in perfromance won't matter, because even the slow code will still be done in a fraction of a second. If perfromance is a concern though, avoid Reflection if at all possible.